# How should I write inline equations in Org Mode so they export to LaTeX properly?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

I have a sentence with the words `42 m s^{-1}`. When this is exported to LaTeX it exports as  `42 m s$^{\text{-1}}$`. How should I write it, or what flags should I set in the `#+OPTIONS:` line, so that it exports as `42 m s^{-1}`?

Comment: I just wrap everything in `$$`, the options you are looking for are probably these: http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html#LaTeX-fragments

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Also, it is good to know that the dollar syntax `$...$` is not always recommended in LaTeX (and the double dollar syntax, `$$...$$`, for displayed equations, in strongly discouraged).  For further info see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503) and [this question on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510).

Needless to say, Org-mode supports both `\(...\)` and `\[...\]`.  Try exporting this to LaTeX:

```
* Dollars
hello $E=mc^2$
* Parens
hello \(E=mc^2\)
* Double dollars
hello $$E=mc^2$$
* Brackets
hello \[E=mc^2\]
```

Comment: Yes, but note that these all cause issues with `pandoc`, except for the $foo$ syntax.

Comment: Oh hi there, mbork! :)  I do have to wonder if org-mode would be able to transform double-dollar to the more proper `\[…\]` as part of its export process.  (It's more of a rhetorical wondering, I suppose—of course you can customize it `:)`)

Comment: @mankoff: I'd consider this a bug in `pandoc`, then.  Dollars (especially the double ones) are *not* proper LaTeX syntax.

Comment: I'd like to point out the comment section of one of the linked answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode#comment83898_513

Answer (score 8):

Just wrap it with the TeX-dollars:

```
$x^2$
```

exports to

```
...
$x^2$
...
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to leave a comment noting how this answer may be improved?

Comment: I was not me but LaTeX dollar syntax is discouraged, as discussed above. I guess that could be why.

Comment: @Thriveth [`$` isn't going anywhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513/17423) – see Frank's comment as linked above; Frank has been in a leadership position with LaTeX for many years now, so his word carries quite a bit of weight.

Comment: You are arguing with the wrong guy... All I know is that `$` is officially discouraged, and I simply guessed that could be the reason why someone else had downvoted this. I am not claiming to be knowledgeable or for that matter having an opinion about whether this is a good idea or not.

Comment: @Thriveth I guess my point is I don't know where you're getting your info -- it needs to be updated. Do you mind sharing?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, in this case where you are working with units, you might consider using [the `siunitx` LaTeX package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). After loading the package in your org file:

```
#+LaTeX_+HEADER: \usepackage{siunitx}
```

you can use `\SI{42}{m.s^{-1}}` in your text. This will make sure that the spaces between quantity and unit are appropriate, e.g. not allowing line breaks between any of the components. Moreover, the `siunitx` package also knows how to properly format numbers like `1.23e45` as `1.23 \times 10^{45}`, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\SI{42}{\meters\per\second}`? I love `siunitx`, but I don't think it works with pandoc and I have to be able to convert to Word...

Comment: You can use either (see e.g. page 5 of the documentation, just above section 4). I personally think the explicit `\meters\per\second` way is too much work :-).